# Responsive image stretching - with a grid based on the y axis?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am biting my teeth out on something that seems quite basic to me - in theory.

**Think about the regular responsive grid that we use every day, as in bootstrap, foundation etc... Then rotate it by 90 degrees:**

[image]

The grey container is an enlarged image with a known aspect ratio (3:2). The blue container is a known number of square images (thumbs) that fit perfectly to the large image. The pink border is the container, which has received a fixed height (like 50vh of `html,body{height:100vh}`). All images have one side on 100% and one on auto.

So the "grey" image should stretch to its container, and then the thumbs should follow. Really, the classic RWD behaviour - just on the y axis.

I've tried:

- Flexbox (not its call here, doesn't help with aspect-ratio-maintenance while stretching parent containers)
- A classic grid, calculating the necessary width of the columns in % (works out in theory, but browser rounding will result in irregularities)
- `display: table` (100% heights don't kick in, and there's no rowspan, tried to nest them, horrible)
- Yes, tables! (Couldn't get the main image to stretch based on it's aspect ratio, and of course, it won't be possible to stack the thumbs for smallscreen)

So going back to the start: is it possible at all to reproduce this `height: 100%, width: auto` style behaviour with pure HTML/CSS?

If yes, which way to go?

If no, why, and what do you recommend as JS workaround?

PS I've already tried foundation's `equalizer` script, again: rounding errors at calculating the height.

PPS: I admit I tried most of the above with zurb foundation 6 loaded (as I'd like to stick to it for other parts of the page), so maybe it interfered with some of the tries?

Comment: Hey, so the number of boxes on the left can change and then you need them to respond accordingly? Or will there always be 8?

Comment: there will be always a fixed / known number (like 8) in my case. Cheers (signing off for today)

Comment: Here's a fiddle my colleague did: http://jsfiddle.net/ursbraem/cvLcx5qk/6/ using flex and padding-bottom hack

Comment: Have you tried using background-size: cover for that image on the left? Then it will always fit its container. For <IE9 support you will simply need this polyfill: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Comment: @NathanielFlick The image shouldn't be cropped. I was really having difficulties getting the containers right. What do you think about the padding-hack in the fiddle in the above comment?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can play with padding and height 0, read this article at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-helprticle http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html, I did a test as well, hope is what you are looking for, check it out http://codepen.io/wolfitoXtreme/pen/bEeYep

```
// CSS
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body, body * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
}
#container #imgMain {
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: -25%;
    margin-top: -37.5%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
#container #imgMain figure {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#container #imgMain img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#container #imgGrid {
    top: 0;
    right: -50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#container #imgGrid figure {
    width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 37.5%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

// HTML
<div id="container">



        <div id="imgMain">

            <figure>
                <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic01.jpg">
            </figure>

            <div id="imgGrid">

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic02.jpg">
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic03.jpg">
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic04.jpg">
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic05.jpg">
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic06.jpg">
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic07.jpg">
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic08.jpg">
                </figure>

                <figure>
                    <img src="http://cssguy4hire.com/codePenAssets/aspectRatio/pic01.jpg">
                </figure>

            </div>

        </div>




</div>
```